# On a system of PDE

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I would like to know what is the set of solutions to the following PDE. I think it consists of just constants, but I need help to prove.  Let $f_1(p_1,p_2)$ and $f_2(p_1,p_2)$ be two functions. The system of equations on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is just:

$$p_1 \partial_{p_1} f_1 + p_2 \partial_{p_1} f_2=0 $$

$$ p_1 \partial_{p_2} f_1 + p_2 \partial_{p_2} f_2 =0 $$

So nobody complain, I want the solutions to be at least of class $C^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$p_1 \partial_{p_1,p2} f_1 + p_2\partial_{p_1,p2} f_2= -\partial_{p_1} f_2 \tag{$\partial_{p_2}\,eq1$}$$

$$ p_1 \partial_{p1,p_2} f_1 + p_2 \partial_{p1,p_2} f_2 = -\partial_{p_2} f_1 \tag{$\partial_{p_1}\,eq2$} $$

So $$ \partial_{p_1} f_2 = \partial_{p_2} f_1 \tag{*}$$ Can you take from here? Now you have PDEs in one unknown. Solve and check whether their solution satisfies (*)...

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance Dr, but I don't understand at all!  1) I guess there is a small mistake in that there should be a $p_2$ multiplying the second term of the first equation.

Comment: So what you want me to do is substitute $y$(either one of the two terms in *) for this quantity and substitute back into the equation and then solve? Ok, I'll give it a try...

Comment: @youngmuppet : Ok corrected it, the $p_2$ is now there. My suggestion is to use $(*)$ and to write *your* eq1 as a function of $f_1$ only and solve it. Then do the same with eq2 but now write it as a function of $f_2$ only. Solve these two new PDEs and check when their solution satisfy $(*)$. My guess is you will get only the constant solutions as you originally guessed.

Comment: Actually it seem like it work out to give f_1=u_1(p_1/p_2), f_2=u_2(p_1/p_2) where -u_2'=xu_1'. Method is very good.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!